# How To Render CSS Inline In ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: css, asp.net, optimization, c#-4.0, bundling-and-minification

I am using System.Web.Optimization to bundle the css and script.But now I want to render css and scripts inline instead of refer to a single file.

I am trying to create an extension method for **System.Web.Optimization.Render()** but I am not able to provide parameter as HttpContextBase for the method **GenerateBundleResponse()**

Following is my code with Error

```
    public static class OptimizationStylesExtention
    {

      private static string GetBundleContent(HttpContextBase httpContextBase, 
        string bundleVirtualPath)
       {
            return BundleTable.Bundles
                .Single(b => b.Path == bundleVirtualPath)
                .GenerateBundleResponse(new BundleContext(httpContextBase, 
                            BundleTable.Bundles, bundleVirtualPath)).Content;
        }

    public static IHtmlString RenderInline(this HtmlString str, params string[] 
    bundleVirtualPath)
    {
        StringBuilder bundleContent = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var virtualPath in bundleVirtualPath)
        {
            bundleContent.Append(BundleTable.Bundles.Single(b => b.Path == virtualPath)
            .GenerateBundleResponse(new BundleContext(str, BundleTable.Bundles, virtualPath)));
        }
        return new HtmlString(string.Format("{<style>{0}</style>}", bundleContent.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is solutions for ASP.NET MVC but I want it for ASP.NET Web Form using C#.
https://codeshare.co.uk/blog/how-to-inline-css-and-javascript-bundles-in-mvc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello you can do using **GenerateBundleResponse** Metho. Which is the method of **BundleResponse** class.

Here is the code

```
using System.Web.Optimization;

/// <summary>
/// This is the extension for the bundle. 
/// Which is used when we want to use inline css with style tag
/// </summary>
public static class BundleExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns inline css with style tag
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="VirtualPath">Accepts Virtual Path</param>
    /// <returns>string as inline css</returns>
    public static string InlineStyle(string VirtualPath)
    {
        var CSSBundle = BundleTable.Bundles.GetBundleFor(VirtualPath);
        var CSS = CSSBundle.GenerateBundleResponse(new BundleContext(new System.Web.HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current), BundleTable.Bundles, string.Empty)).Content;
        return string.Format("<style type='text/css'>{0}</style>",CSS);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns inline script with script tag
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="VirtualPath">Accepts Virtual Path</param>
    /// <returns>string as inline script</returns>
    public static string InlineScript(string VirtualPath)
    {
        var JSBundle = BundleTable.Bundles.GetBundleFor(VirtualPath);
        var JS = JSBundle.GenerateBundleResponse(new BundleContext(new System.Web.HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current), BundleTable.Bundles, string.Empty)).Content;
        return string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>{0}</script>", JS);
    }
}
```

And In your ASP.NET Page, You can call that method as follows

```
<%=BundleExtensions.InlineStyle("~/css/new_home_page") %>
```

Thank You :)